# Soluble or insoluble?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, water

In the picture attached [here](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UMqPKQKamhk/hqdefault.jpg), is the compound in water soluble or insoluble?

I get confused while identifying solubility of a solute in a solvent when a situation like this arrises. The crystals of the solid have become liquid, but they give a certain transluscent white colour to the solvent (water in this case). So in this picture, is the solute soluble in water?

Comment: A true solution must be transparent.

Comment: It is impossible to determine just from the image. All solutes have a limited solubility, so you can always reach a point where the solution is saturated. Also soluble is a fuzzy concept. Is soluble having 1 gram, or 0.1 gram, or 1 milligram of a solute being dissolved in 100ml of water?